# Python/Pygame - Create "End credits" like the ones at the end of a movie

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to create "end credits" like the ones at the end of a movie, using pygame. I've googled for other ways to achieve this using python, but I haven't found any yet.

I've almost achieved this with the following code: http://pastebin.com/nyjxeDYQ

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
import threading
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

# Initialise pygame + other settings
pygame.init()
pygame.fastevent.init()
event_get = pygame.fastevent.get
pygame.display.set_caption('End credits')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1920, 1080))
background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background = background.convert()
background.fill((255, 255, 255))
fontsize = 40
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", fontsize)
x = 0

def main():
    global x
    credit_list = ["CREDITS - The Departed"," ","Leonardo DiCaprio - Billy","Matt Damon - Colin Sullivan", "Jack Nicholson - Frank Costello", "Mark Wahlberg - Dignam", "Martin Sheen - Queenan"]

    going = True
    while going:
        events = event_get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type in [QUIT]:
                going = False
            if e.type in [KEYDOWN] and e.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                going = False

        # Loop that creates the end credits
        ypos = screen.get_height()
        while ypos > (0 - len(credit_list)*50) and x == 0: # Loop through pixel by pixel, screenheight + height of all the textlines combined
            drawText(credit_list,ypos)
            ypos = ypos - 1
        x = 1

    pygame.quit()

def drawText(text,y):
    for line in text:
        text = font.render(line, 1, (10, 10, 10))
        textpos = text.get_rect()
        textpos.centerx = background.get_rect().centerx
        background.blit(text, (textpos.x,y))
        y = y + 45

    # Blit all the text    
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()
    time.sleep(0.0001) # Sleep function to adjust speed of the end credits

    # Blit white background (else all the text will stay visible)
    background.fill((255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

The problem is that the scrolling text is flickering. This is because I use a time.sleep()-function to control the speed of the scrolling. When I use a value like 0.04 sec, it works pretty well, but the text moves too slow and there is still a bit of flickering. When I use a much lower value, like: 0.001 sec, the text is moving at a speed that I like, but there is a lot more flickering going on.

There is another value I can use to adjust the speed of the scrolling: the number of pixels to move. But when I set this to anything higher than 1, the scrolling isn't smooth anymore.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem? I don't necessarily have to use pygame, I do have to use python though.

Many thanks in advance!

Albrecht

Comment: You should decide on a reasonable frame rate, and then change the speed by changing the number of pixels to more per frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some simpe rule you should follow that will help you with your problem:

- Don't call `pygame.display.flip()` more than once per frame
- Don't use `time.sleep()` to control the speed of something in your application
- Use a `Clock` to control the framerate

Here's a cleaned up, minimal working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('End credits')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
screen_r = screen.get_rect()
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 40)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def main():

    credit_list = ["CREDITS - The Departed"," ","Leonardo DiCaprio - Billy","Matt Damon - Colin Sullivan", "Jack Nicholson - Frank Costello", "Mark Wahlberg - Dignam", "Martin Sheen - Queenan"]

    texts = []
    # we render the text once, since it's easier to work with surfaces
    # also, font rendering is a performance killer
    for i, line in enumerate(credit_list):
        s = font.render(line, 1, (10, 10, 10))
        # we also create a Rect for each Surface. 
        # whenever you use rects with surfaces, it may be a good idea to use sprites instead
        # we give each rect the correct starting position 
        r = s.get_rect(centerx=screen_r.centerx, y=screen_r.bottom + i * 45)
        texts.append((r, s))

    while True:
        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == QUIT or e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                return

        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

        for r, s in texts:
            # now we just move each rect by one pixel each frame
            r.move_ip(0, -1)
            # and drawing is as simple as this
            screen.blit(s, r)

        # if all rects have left the screen, we exit
        if not screen_r.collidelistall([r for (r, _) in texts]):
            return

        # only call this once so the screen does not flicker
        pygame.display.flip()

        # cap framerate at 60 FPS
        clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I tried to accomplish! I accept this as the answer!

Comment: fyi all: if, like me, you're looking to record a video with these credits, try "vidmaker", worked for me